# Insert POINT using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, spatial, mysql-workbench

I've got a table that contains a POINT column. I was wondering whether it is possible to insert a point using the Inserts tab in MySQL Workbench. I've tried a number of different combinations to no avail:

1 1

1,1

(1 1)

(1,1)

POINT(1 1)

POINT(1,1)

GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well not the exact answer u r looking for , but for a pass by , u can try
a float field and while retrieving programmatically calculate the value before and after the '.' symbol , considering x and y co-ordinates , this worked for me 
other wise u can have two separate columns for x and y co-ordinates